# How to import .dmx files (SFM sessions) into Blender

Tags: export, import

I downloaded a model for SFM but the model is in .dmx format instead of .mdl format. Is there any way I can get the model from the .dmx file?

Answer (score 1):

I am a complete noob when it comes to this, but I have found a bunch of videos and written a short list on how to get models from steam source filmmaker to blender with textures. This may or may not be helpful to you. The Youtube video I linked does not explain everything, but he gets you set up with most of the programs. I was able to get Lifeline from Apex Legends character model imported with bones, but I had to retexture myself. These are the personal notes I made.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXd_1aKBTF8

Moving Character Models from Steam to Blender
Programs Needed - Blender, VTFEdit, Crowbar, Steam - Join Source Filmmaker

1. Go to source Filmmaker on Steam browser
2. Don't open it. Type in search bar for model
3. Open crowbar and click download tab
4. Copy link on steam and paste in Item ID or link bar
5. Change output to folder name
6. Click download
7. Click on Decompile tab
8. Browse for MDL file in the created folder from step 5
9. Choose an output to folder
10. Click decompile
11. Once in blender, click import smd
12. Use VTFEdit for textures
13. Click on tools
14. Convert folder button in order to convert vmt files to png files
15. Use blender shader editor to apply textures

    - Image Texture => Color Ramp and Principled Shader
    - Color Ramp => Bump
    - Bump => Displacement on Material Output Node
    - Principled Shader => Surface on Material Output Node

[image]